# Apache and Node on same IP

Tags: node.js, apache, virtualhost

I have a single VPS with one IP. I'm using Apache to serve `cloud.mysite.com` and I have a NodeJS application listening on port 3000.

I'm trying to configure my VPS in a way so that when I visit `mysite.com`, I get my NodeJS application.

Instead, when I visit `mysite.com`, I'm forwarded to `cloud.mysite.com`.

My `.conf` files are below.

mysite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>   
    ServerName mysite.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off  
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

cloud.mysite.com

```
<VirtualHost cloud.mysite.com:80>

  ServerName cloud.mysite.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.mysite.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost cloud.mysite.com:443>

  # Basics
  ServerName www.cloud.mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.cloud.mysite.com
  # Next line puts ownCloud at the domain root instead of a /owncloud/ subdirectory (e.g. example.com vs. example.com/owncloud/)
  Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"
  DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

  # SSTL STUFF GOES HERE

  # ownCloud
  <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud

  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
SSLStaplingCache        shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
```

**Edit: I resolved this by clearing my cache.**

Comment: you want to forword mysite.com to cloud.mysite.com ?

Comment: No. I'm trying to have my NodeJS application on mysite.com and Apache serve my site on cloud.mysite.com

Comment: both on same machine ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it should proxy requests to your Node app if it's running on and listening on port 3000 on the same host, or fail if it isn't - but not to proxy requests to the other virtual host.

Make sure that you restarted Apache or made it reload the configuration after you made those changes and that your new config file is where it should be and is enabled.

Comment: I've made extra sure, I have the correct configuration enabled and I've restarted apache more times than I can count. Running out of ideas myself.

Comment: @Atonium You can try to temporarily remove the `VirtualHost mysite.com:80` config, restart and see if it stopped working. It should stop serving mysite.com - if it isn't it means that something else is serving it and you should track it down what it is. It may be in some other config. My advice would be to try to break serving the main mysite.com and see which step made it stop work and go from there.

Comment: Well both, mysite.com and cloud.mysite.com, have the same A Record with my DNS provider. Am I handling that incorrectly?

Comment: It was my browser's cache, sadly. I triple checked everything and finally decided to use a web proxy and it was served up perfectly. Cleared cache, viola.